# Arukh HaShulḥan on the number of times we say ashrei

Tags: tefilla, kedusha-prayer, aruch-hashulchan

The [Arukh HaShulḥan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aruch_HaShulchan) gives several reasons for us repeating ashrei ([Ps 145](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.145?lang=bi) plus attendant verses) multiple times during our daily prayers. In his first reason, he connects it with the kedusha of the amida and the kedusha in the uva l'tziyon paragraph, as he writes [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.132.1?vhe=Arukh_HaShulchan,_Orach_Chayim_--_Wikisource&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (square-bracket additions are mine):

> ‮דכשם שבשחרית יש שני קדושות, לבד קדושה ד"יוצר" שאינו אלא סיפור איך המלאכים אומרים קדושה, ולכן יש שני פעמים "אשרי" בשחרית. ובמנחה יש קדושה אחת – תיקנו פעם אחת "אשרי". ובערבית ליכא קדושה – לא תיקנו כלל.
>
> Just as in shaḥarit there are two kedushot (besides the kedusha in "yotzer" *[the first of the two brachot before sh'ma]*, which is simply a description of how the angels say kedusha), therefore there we say "ashrei" twice in shaḥarit. And at minḥa, there is one kedusha, so they established "ashrei" once. And at arvit, there is no kedusha, so they didn't establish it *[ashrei]* at all.

He goes on to explain how verses in ashrei correspond to the kedusha. Anyhow, this one-to-one correspondence works out fine during the week, but on days with musaf (or ne'ila), it doesn't hold. On shabbat, for example, we have ashrei before the shaḥarit amida and ashrei before the musaf amida, but minḥa has two kedushot (one in the uva l'tziyon paragraph and one in the amida) but only one ashrei, and in the evening, there is another uva l'tziyon paragraph without an ashrei. The Arukh HaShulḥan does write ([here](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.292.1?vhe=Arukh_HaShulchan,_Orach_Chayim_--_Wikisource&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that the ashrei + uva l'tziyon at minḥa on shabbat is pushed off from shaḥarit, but doesn't address there (that I see) why this ashrei double-counts (if it does) for the kedusha of the minḥa amida. The count is similarly off for any day with musaf.

Does the Arukh HaShulḥan (or others who play off his reasoning) address this anywhere?

*Note: I'm not looking for other reasons for repeating ashrei, just in understanding this one.*

Comment: While the machloket rishonim if kedusha dyotzer and kdusha disidra are "real" or "sippur devarim" is well known, does anyone ever distinguish between the two?

Comment: @DoubleAA Besides the arukh hashulḥan here, you mean?

Comment: He doesn't though https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%91#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%97

Comment: @DoubleAA In the question of דברים שבקדושה he doesn't distinguish, but he clearly distinguishes them in *some* respect in OḤ 132:1 that I'm quoting.

Comment: @DoubleAA I've been pointed to a chapter in Ruth Langer's *To Worship God Properly*, but haven't had a chance to look through it.

Comment: @magicker72 you are right, my answer was not about Ashrei.

Comment: It also doesn't work out on rosh chodesh when there are 3x kedusha but only ashrei twice; before shemona esrei and before musaf. My guess is we simply don't increase from 3x in one day since that is the number the gemera in brachos says is connected to receiving olam haba.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ran on Megillah 23b (ד״ה כל דבר) cites Raavad who differentiates. Same in Ran on Rif Megillah 13b ד״ה ושמעי׳.